# Python pandas: Return indices of all rows like another row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Suppose we have a toy example like below.

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, 
                                    high=2, 
                                    size=(5, 2)))
df

    0   1
0   1   1
1   0   0
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   0
```

We want to return the indices of all rows like a certain row. Suppose I want the indices of all rows like `row 0`, which has a 1 in both `column 0` and `column 1`.

I would want a data structure that has: `(0, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it like this

```
df.index[df.eq(df.iloc[0]).all(1)].tolist()

[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: So it is really super, I have to admire you very often ;) So sorry for timings, I was curious about it and it is no reason for post it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One way may be to use `lambda`:

```
df.index[df.apply(lambda row: all(row == df.iloc[0]), axis=1)].tolist()
```

Other way may be to use mask :

```
df.index[df[df == df.iloc[0].values].notnull().all(axis=1)].tolist()
```

Result:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```